# Arista 7050S can handle 600x SVI?

Tags: arista

i have read Arista 7050S datasheet and everything is fit on my project, but i could not find anywhere that if 7050S can handle 500x SVI ?
can any one guide me?
thank you.

Comment: I would strong suggest that if you need that many SVIs, you need to rethink your network topology and break things up with some routers. It implies many of levels of layer-2 switches trunking many VLANs with traffic from thousands ( or tens of thousands) of hosts through layer-2, and that is going to be a poor design.

Comment: Ron, your mean is it can not handle 600x SVI ? because we have some limitations in hardware and because layer3 switches can handle better throughput we want to use l3 swicthes, so if i have 400x SVIs on arista 7050s it will impact CPU load ? and may cause problem? and face high cpu usages?

Comment: I did not say that. I think the topology that requires 600 SVIs on one switch is a very bad idea. A spanning tree loop in such a topology will be a huge disaster. You really want to rethink it, and break it up with routers to isolate problems.

Comment: i got it, so you think the main issue will be STP and loops right? do you think the cpu can handle 400-500x SVIs ?

Comment: I do not have an answer to that, else I would have posted an answer. I am merely telling you that you are setting yourself up for big problems in the future with a poor network design, and you should not even need to ask the question if you do a proper design.

Comment: I don't think the number of SVIs itself will have any impact in performance but the more SVIs you have IN USE (as in how many hosts are using them as their gateway, equating to how much traffic is flowing through the switch) is what would increase your CPU utilization. If you have 600 SVIs (you have that many different networks for whatever reason), I think you need to rethink how you classify each host and either group them (like if you're separating printers by brand instead of just "printers") or add some routers or at least separate layer 3 switches into the environment to break up load.